# How to know the actual count in a huge table with high insertion rate

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table with exactly 10M rows. I need to know the exact count of the rows. A `COUNT` request takes 5 seconds. Let's say exactly 100 rows are added to the table every second.

If I ask the DB the count at the moment it has exactly 10,000,000 rows, and this request takes exactly 5 seconds to complete, will the result be `10000000`, `10000500` or something between these two values?

Comment: Do you ever delete rows?

Comment: Well usually not, but in a case where there's bad data or something I guess I could have to delete some rows

Answer (score 1):

If you are not running the statement inside an explicit transaction, then the count it gives will be correct as-of the moment the statement started executing, so `10000000` not `10000500`.

If you are running it inside a transaction, the exact behavior depends on the isolation level you use, and what happened previously in that transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table has an auto-increment id column, you can execute this in a couple of milliseconds:

```
select max(id) - min(id)
from my_big_table
```

This assumes you don't have any gaps, which is the typical case.

Actually, you can know exactly the delta of how many rows are "missing" by running this once:

```
select max(id) - count(*) from my_big_table
```

And remembering the value. Unless you delete rows, this won't change (if you do delete rows, run it again).

Now that you know the delta, this will be accurate:

```
select max(id) - <delta>
from my_big_table
```

Which will be accurate and extremely fast, so you don't need to worry about the implications of slow queries.

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a different question.  He is asking if a long `COUNT` query can return a different row count than the table had when the query started if rows are added in the middle of the query, while this answer seems to be about computing the row count efficiently, which (while a good shot at optimization) does not answer the question.

Comment: @cdhowie Well, I interpret the question as existing because the query takes so long. If there's a query that is near instantaneous, the question is "answered" because it renders it moot.

Comment: That may be true, but an answer to the actual question posed could still be useful to future visitors.  As written, this answer makes assumptions about the table that may not be accurate both in this case and in the case of future visitors.

Comment: Thanks for this neat trick, I will surely use it in some other cases eventually! Very efficient! But I don't think in my case it's a durable solution, since I can't guarantee the `id` column won't have any gaps